# Symfony2: Inject current user in Service

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to inject the currently logged in user into a service. My goal is to extend some twig functionality to output it based on user preferences. In this example I want to output any date function using the user specific Timezone.

There doesn't seem to be any way to inject the current user into a service, which seems really odd to me. When injecting the security context, it doesn't have a token even if the user is logged in

I am using FOS user bundle.

```
services:
    ...
    twigdate.listener.request:
        class: App\AppBundle\Services\TwigDateRequestListener
        arguments: [@twig, @security.context]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }


<?php

namespace App\AppBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class TwigDateRequestListener
{
    protected $twig;

    function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, SecurityContext $context) {

        $this->twig = $twig;
        //$this->user = $context->get...;

        var_dump($context); die;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
       // $this->twig->getExtension('core')->setDateFormat($user->getProfile()->getFormat());
       // $this->twig->getExtension('core')->setTimeZone($user->getProfile()->getTimezone());
    }
}

output:

object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext)[325]
  private 'token' => null
  private 'accessDecisionManager' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManager)[150]
      private 'voters' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\RoleHierarchyVoter)[151]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\AuthenticatedVoter)[153]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Voter\AclVoter)[155]
              ...
      private 'strategy' => string 'decideAffirmative' (length=17)
      private 'allowIfAllAbstainDecisions' => boolean false
      private 'allowIfEqualGrantedDeniedDecisions' => boolean true
  private 'authenticationManager' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager)[324]
      private 'providers' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider)[323]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AnonymousAuthenticationProvider)[149]
              ...
      private 'eraseCredentials' => boolean true
  private 'alwaysAuthenticate' => boolean false
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would use a twig extension for that:

```
class UserDateExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $context;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->context->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'user_date' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, "formatUserDate"),
        );
    }

    public function formatUserDate($date, $format)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        // do stuff
    }
```

Now in `services.xml`

```
    <service id="user_date_twig_extension" class="%user_date_twig_extension.class%">
        <tag name="twig.extension" />
        <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
    </service>
```

Then in twig you could do:

```
{{ date | user_date('d/m/Y') }}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I still don't understand why my first example didn't return the user object, but I got it working, and I think a Twig Extension is actually a cleaner approach. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Well you were listening for `kernel.request` event. Setting context token by authentication or reading token from session are done after all `kernel.request` listeners are dispatched. If you have listened for `kernel.response` event then you would have get desired token. Also sorry to misread your question. It is a bad day for me :).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explenation. You learn something every day.

Comment: SecurityContext (security.context) is deprecated since 2.6.
Use security.token_storage instead

Comment: In addition to the comment from @nutrija, see: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

Answer (score 59):

I think that this question deserves an updated answer since 2.6.x+ since the new security component improvements.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

class UserDateExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var TokenStorage
     */
    protected $tokenStorage;


    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage    $tokenStorage
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'user_date' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, "formatUserDate"),
        );
    }

    public function formatUserDate($date, $format)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Services.yml

```
twig.date_extension:
    class: Acme\Twig\SpecialDateExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
    arguments:
        - "@security.token_storage"
```

Answer (score 30):

services.yml

```
my_service:
    class: ...
    arguments:
        - "@=service('security.token_storage').getToken().getUser()"
```

Service.php

```
protected $currentUser;

public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->currentUser = $user;
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language

Comment: This is the best answer in 2016 for symfony 2.6 and up

Comment: Does it work outside of a security firewall?
I mean, does it return "null" or does it throw an exception because getToken() returns null and ->getUser() cannot be applied on a null object?

Comment: Works fine for Symfony 3.2

Comment: I believe this was throwing errors when there's no user.

Answer (score 4):

The user is a bad candidate to be a service.

- First it is a model not a service
- Second there is service *security.context* where you can get user from.

In a twig template you can use *app.user*. See symfony doc [global-template-variables](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html#global-template-variables).
If you want to show something based on user permissions you can do {{ is_granted('ROLE_USER') }}.

Answer (score 2):

From Symfony 2.6.

You need use @security.token_storage

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class UserDateExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
/**
 * @var TokenStorageInterface
 */
protected $tokenStorage;


/**
 * @param $tokenStorage TokenStorage
 */
public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
}

public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        'user_date' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, "formatUserDate"),
    );
}

public function formatUserDate($date, $format)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    // do stuff
}
```

}

And Services.yml

```
twig.date_extension:
    class: Acme\Twig\SpecialDateExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
```

reference:  http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend binding a different event, if you use the kernel.controller event, you will have a token and have no problem. The token is not available in `kernel.request` since `Symfony 2.3`

I wrote a guide on how to implement User Timezones for `Symfony 2.3+` and `2.6+` in Twig on my blog called [Symfony 2.6+ User Timezones](http://io.ofbeaton.com/2015/06/symfony-2-6-user-timezones/).

This is vastly superior to using a Twig Extension because you can use the standard date formatting functions in Twig, as well as provide separate backend UTC date, default Twig date timezones and User defined Twig date timezones.

Here is the most important excerpt:

*src/AppBundle/EventListener/TwigSubscriber.php*

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class TwigSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $twig;
    protected $tokenStorage;

    function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'kernel.controller' => 'onKernelController'
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();

        if ($token !== null) {
            $user = $token->getUser();

            if ($user instanceof User) {
                $timezone = $user->getTimezone();
                if ($timezone !== null) {
                    $this->twig->getExtension('core')->setTimezone($timezone);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use twig as normal and it uses your User preferences if available.

Answer (score -9):

You can try injecting `@service_container` and do `$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();`.

Comment: Injecting the whole container is a bad idea in most cases. Instead you should inject each service you need explicitly.

Comment: @elnur, Tell that to [FriendsOfSymfony](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/Twig/Extension/FacebookExtension.php#L26) :)

Comment: Twig extensions is one of the exceptions to this rule.

Comment: @elnur, Sorry I was wrong. It seems that the helper service `FacebookExtension` uses have [templating.helper](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/facebook.xml#L26) tag. Which may conflict with the extension. You are right injecting `@service_container` is a bad Idea.

Comment: You can inject just `security.context`. You do not need to inject all the service container.

Comment: Don't inject the whole container !

Comment: @skonsoft, yes you are right. At the time I answered the question I had confusion about service locator anti-pattern. But still I did not update the answer because I wanted to leave trace of my own stupidity at that time :)

Comment: Never inject the whole container!!