# Symfony2 : Why getToken return null when injecting SecurityContext in a TwigExtension?

Tags: symfony, twig, security-context

I did exactly the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990625/symfony2-inject-current-user-in-service) but the token property is null and the user is correctly logged in and the route is behind a firewall. Also, I am injecting the SecurityContext in other services and it works fine.

services.xml :

```
<service id="tc.extensions.relation_helper"
 class="TC\CoreBundle\Extensions\RelationHelperExtension">
    <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
    <tag name="twig.extension" />
</service>
```

My extension:

```
class RelationHelperExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var User 
     */
    private $user;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext){
        $this->user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the security context to a field and using it in the `getUser()` method to get the current user instead of doing that right in the constructor?

Comment: Thanks @ElnurAbdurrakhimov it helps! I guess, when the security context is passed, the user is not instantiated yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Elnur_Abdurrakhimov said we must cache the securityContext first and the call the `getToken()->getUser()` when needed.

```
class RelationHelperExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    private $context;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext){
        $this->context= $securityContext;
    }

    private function getUser(){
            return $this->context->getToken()->getUser();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks to your comment I notice @Elnur_Abdurrakhimov comment

Answer (score 3):

To understand this behavior :

Twig_Extension are instancied BEFORE SecurityContext init sequence => at this moment SecurityContext is empty

But if you store it in a attribute, when you USE your own twig extension serviceyou are (in most of case) in a Request scope & SecurityContext is initalized with good values :)