# getUser in Symfony2's service constructor

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I have a very strange problem in one of my Symfony2's service.
I want to get the current user in the constructor of my service but the SecurityContext->getToken return false!

That is my service constructor :

```
public function __construct(Registry $doctrine, SecurityContext $context){
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    $this->context = $context;
    if(!$this->context->getToken()){
        echo "Il y a une merde au niveau du token !";
    }
    $this->my_auth = $this->getMyAuth();
}
```

And here the service declaration in my service.yml

```
security.autorisation:
    class: Nsi\SecurityBundle\Service\Autorisation
    arguments: [@doctrine,@security.context]
```

But when I go on my admin page, the message "Il y a une merde au niveau du Token" appear.
the most surprising is that my bottom symfony toolbar show me my login !

My project is a Symfony 2.3.11 project

Thinks for your help

Comment: try isGranted() on context !

Comment: cache the securityContext first and the call the getToken()->getUser() when needed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770467/symfony2-why-gettoken-return-null-when-injecting-securitycontext-in-a-twigexte)

Comment: I need to execute a query in my constructor who use user informations. How can I use cache system for security context in my case ?

Comment: Why do you need to run any query token related inside a service constructor? could you clarify your question please?

Comment: I have tried your solution and it's work, but not fully optimized.
I use this service many time in a page, so for optimise database connexions I think the best solution is to get my informations in constructor and put them in a property to get this in my function who is called many times.

Comment: The security.context acts as a cache.  Calling getToken multiple times wont hit the database.  Are you injecting your Autorization class into an event listener?  It seems like it is being used before the security listener has a chance to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call it from service constructor, because service initialization called earlier than authentication. That's why you have no token set.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function __construct(Registry $doctrine, SecurityContext $context){
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    $this->context = $context;
    if(!$this->context->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))){
       echo "Il y a une merde au niveau du token !";
    }
    $this->my_auth = $this->getMyAuth();
}
```

Comment: not working. I have this error : AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.