# Symfony2 Setter Injection doesnt works

Tags: symfony, model, code-injection, propel, setter

I build my business logic with propel. All the models extends an abstract model, in which I want to inject the security context:

Services.yml

```
parameters:
    Abstract.Model : 'FooBundle\Model\AbstractModel'

services:
    Abstract.Model:
        class: 'FooBundle\Model\AbstractModel'
        calls:
            - [setSecurity, ["@security.context"]]
```

The AbstractModel

```
abstract class AbstractModel extends BaseObject
{
    /**
     * @param $security \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext
     */
    protected $security;

    /**
     * Sets the security context
     *
     * @param $security \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext
     */
    public function setSecurity($security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * Code to be run before persisting the object
     *
     * @param PropelPDO $con
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function preSave(\PropelPDO $con = null)
    {
        $token = $this->security->getToken();
    }
}
```

If propel runs the preSave method, it responses with a 500:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getToken() on a non-object
```

Anyone know whats going wrong here?

Greetings

Update_01:

```
public function save(PropelPDO $con = null, $skipReload = false)
{
    ...
    $ret = $this->preSave($con);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the *user* code that's triggering `preSave` ?

Comment: Hey, I've updated my code example from above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: An Abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Well, to do short, you need to call your model from the service container. Since your class is abstract, my guess is that you didn't set any [`parent`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html) on the concrete class declaration

Comment: Ah I see...Well, seems that I cant do this with DI, because I never call this model. Its just an wrapper for all of my concrete models, and I want to be able, to insert created_by and updated_by user id. thats the reason, why I need the security context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Extend your Abstract class:

```
class MyModel extends AbstractModel 
{
}
```

and use this class as service:

```
services:
    My.Model:
        class: 'FooBundle\Model\MyModel'
        calls:
            - [setSecurity, ["@security.context"]]
```

Comment: Hm...I just kicked the abstract keyword for testing purposes, but it doesn't works anyway. same error. Is there something wrong with my configuration? Please tell me, if you need more information.

Comment: two reasons: 1. You have to empty the Chache (php app/console cache:clear) and 2. The security.context acts as a cache. Remove getToken() and call it when needed. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116642/getuser-in-symfony2s-service-constructor#comment33554223_22116642