# how to pass username to rollbar via monolog, symfony2

Tags: symfony, monolog, rollbar

I am using rollbar.com to collect all details about exceptions in symfony2 app. However I don't understand how can I configure monolog so it would pass username and user id to rollbar.

I see that I can pass [rollbar config](https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-php/) as shown [here](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L244) and I am thinking `person_fn` is what I need. Still I don't know where to put this function (this should be in service because I need to check security token) and how to pass it to rollbar.

```
# config_prod.yml
rollbar:
    type: rollbar
    level: error
    token: %rollbar_token%
    config:
        person_fn: getUserForRollbarRightAboutNowOrSomething
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution:

- update monolog/monolog bundle to at least 1.17.0 version.
- create ContextProcessor and update user information

  ```
  #src/AppBundle/Monolog/RollbarContextProcessor

  namespace AppBundle\Monolog;

  use AppBundle\Entity\User;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

  class RollbarContextProcessor
  {
      private $tokenStorage;

      public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
      {
          $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
      }

      public function processRecord($record)
      {
          if ($this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
              $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

              if ($user instanceof User) {
                  $record['context']['payload']['person'] = [
                      'id' => $user->getId(),
                      'username' => $user->getUsername(),
                      'email' => $user->getEmail(),
                  ];
              }
          }

          return $record;
      }
  }
  ```
- configure ContextProcessor as service with `monolog.processor` tag.

  ```
  # app/config/config_prod.yml
  services:
      monolog.processor.rollbar_context:
          class: AppBundle\Monolog\RollbarContextProcessor
          arguments:  [@security.token_storage]
          tags:
              - { name: monolog.processor, method: processRecord, handler: rollbar }
  monolog:
      handlers:
          rollbar:
              type: rollbar
              level: error
              token: %rollbar_token%
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts:

### Rollbar

`person_fn` is exactly what you need. You should be able to add a reference to the function by using a string (e.g.: `"MyClass::static_function_reference"` or `"my_function_name"`).

### Symfony

*Disclaimer: I don't use or know much about Symfony.*

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7680917/456188) has some excellent examples of how to get the current user in Symfony. (Punch line: in a controller you can call `$this.getUser()`)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9990625/456188) has a good example of how to *inject* the current user in a service. (Make a Twig Extension that depends on the `SecurityContext` or `TokenStorage`, use those dependencies to get a user objet).

Finally, there's the classic PHP move: as soon as you have a user add it to `$_REQUEST`.  I'm not sure if Symfony co-opts this, but it'd be a valid way in a non-framework PHP application.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer and inspiration to keep digging. However this was symfony framework specific as you can see in my own answer.

Comment: Glad you found a solution in any case!